# How to send GET request to HTTP Client to retrieve data based on a parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

In my Angular app, I am able to send a HTTP GET request to a JSON-server & retrieve data from a JSON file.

Here is some of the code in my `JobService` at the moment:

```
getJob(id: number): Observable<IJob> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IJob>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

getJobs(): Observable<IJob[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IJob[]>(this.baseUrl)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

And here is the `IJob` interface:

```
export interface IJob {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    employeeId?: number;
    managerId: string;
}
```

Here is my `component` code that calls the above methods:

```
loadExistingJobs() {
    this._jobService.getJobs().subscribe(
        (listJobs) => {
            this.jobs = listJobs;
        },
        (err) => console.log(err)
    );
}

getJob(id: number) {
    this._jobService.getJob(id).subscribe(
        (job: IJob) => {
            this.editJob(job);
            this.job = job;
        },
        (err) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Using the above code, I am able to retrieve all existing jobs & a specific job based on the jobId.

Now, I need to figure out how to retrieve all the jobs based on the managerId. I.e. I want to only display the jobs where the ManagerId = 1.

Can someone please tell me what needs to be done to do this?

Do I need to send a different GET request with a `ManagerId` parameter, or do I filter the data returned from `getJobs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to implement separate API for getting Jobs Based on **managerId** you have to change your Backend API as well. But it can be achieved simply as follows. filter data which you got from **`getJobs`** API call based on **managerId**.

```
filteredJobs: any;
managerId: string = "1";

    loadExistingJobs() {
        this._jobService.getJobs().subscribe(
            (listJobs) => {
                this.jobs = listJobs;
                this.filteredJobs = this.jobs.filter(job => job.managerId === this.managerId);
            },
            (err) => console.log(err)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue depends on your REST API and your Design

If you can add new REST API, it's recommended to add a new REST Service that return "Jobs" based on "ManagerID" (The optimized solution)

If not, you can filter the returned list by:

```
loadExistingJobsByManagerId(managerId: string) {
    this._jobService.getJobs().subscribe(
        (listJobs) => {
            this.jobs = listJobs;
            this.filtered = listJobs.filter(job => job.managerId === managerId);
        },
        (err) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This I believe is more related to APIs that you're using and exists. Here you can do either:

1. call another API (IF exists) who will accept "ManagerID" and will
   return all the jobs based on the Manager Id.
2. Otherwise You can filter data from getJobs API (IF pt. 1 API doesn't exist).

Hope it'll help you to get idea. Also you may like to ask your API developer of this project about above suggested API(pt. 1).